# How to 'update' or 'overwrite' a python list

Tags: python, list, overriding, overwrite

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
aList.append(2014)
print aList
```

which produces o/p  `[123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 2014]`

What should be done to overwrite/update this list.
I want the o/p to be

`[2014, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You may try this

```
alist[0] = 2014
```

but if you are not sure about the position of 123 then you may try like this:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(alist):
   if 123 in item:
       alist[idx] = 2014
```

Comment: why you use `in` to compare list items (numbers ..)?

Comment: shouldn't it be `if 123 == item`? What if there is `12345`?

Answer (score 12):

What about replace the item if you know the position:

```
aList[0]=2014
```

Or if you don't know the position loop in the list, find the item and then replace it

```py
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
    for i,item in enumerate(aList):
      if item==123:
        aList[i]=2014
        break
    
    print aList
```

Comment: why no `break` after finding the target item ?

Comment: Edited as suggested

Answer (score 3):

I think it is more pythonic:

```
aList.remove(123)
aList.insert(0, 2014)
```

more useful:

```
def shuffle(list, to_delete, to_shuffle, index):
    list.remove(to_delete)
    list.insert(index, to_shuffle)
    return

list = ['a', 'b']
shuffle(list, 'a', 'c', 0)
print list
>> ['c', 'b']
```

Comment: This works only for integers not if I want to insert def in place of abc. I wanted a generic solution.. not hardcoded.

Comment: I don't know why you think that, pyLearner. Please spend some time with the documentation for Python lists.

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient solution compared to replacing the element in-place directly (e.g. Kerby's solution)

Answer (score 2):

I'm learning to code and I found this same problem. I believe the easier way to solve this is literaly overwriting the list like @kerby82 said:

An item in a list in Python can be set to a value using the form

**x[n] = v**

Where **x** is the name of the list, **n** is the index in the array and **v** is the value you want to set.

In your exemple:

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
aList[0] = 2014
print aList
>>[2014, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer it without enumerate and instead use "range" like this:

```
for item in range(0, len(alist)):
   if 123 in alist[item]:
      alist[item] = 2014
```

For those who are new to python it might be more readable and a little smarter to recap.

Regards P.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to take a value from the same array and trying to update it, you can use the following code.

```
{  'condition': { 
                     'ts': [   '5a81625ba0ff65023c729022',
                               '5a8161ada0ff65023c728f51',
                               '5a815fb4a0ff65023c728dcd']}
```

If the collection is userData['condition']['ts'] and we need to

```
    for i,supplier in enumerate(userData['condition']['ts']): 
        supplier = ObjectId(supplier)
        userData['condition']['ts'][i] = supplier
```

The output will be

```
{'condition': {   'ts': [   ObjectId('5a81625ba0ff65023c729022'),
                            ObjectId('5a8161ada0ff65023c728f51'),
                            ObjectId('5a815fb4a0ff65023c728dcd')]}
```